# Print from Array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to get some data from an array and print it on a UILabel in Xcode, but I get the warning:

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString *' from 'NSArray *'

Here is my code:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
NSArray *results =  [res objectForKey:@"current_observation"];
NSArray *cur = [results valueForKey:@"weather"];
NSArray *tmp = [results valueForKey:@"temp_c"];
NSLog(@"Current conditions: %@, %@º", cur, tmp);

temp.text = (@"%@", tmp);
```

Comment: temp.text = [tmp description];

Comment: The `description` method should never be used to show the result to the user. The `description` method is only to be used for debugging purposes. The output of the `description` method for any class is rarely documented and could change in the future.

Comment: @rmaddy So what method should I use?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff It depends on how you wish to format the contents of the array. The answer by Ahmed is one solution (though I would use a comma to separate the values instead of the empty string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
temp.text = (@"%@", tmp);
```

Use this:

```
temp.text = [tmp componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: I used @creker answer because your code made my app crash. Still trying to figure out why. But thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: well no problem with that but plz find out whu its crashing as it should not crash at all on this

Comment: By the way I figured out what was wrong. And this solution is obviously was better than using the description method as that may change. Thanks :)

Comment: heheh :) I do this sometimes. Reply to message and so on for fun... :)

Comment: You want to combine NSStrings?

Comment: No. I originally thought you suggested this as a good replacement for the description method. But as I have been testing this, I have found that it just doesn't work and makes my app crash. But the description method work beautifully. I basically need some method or whatever which will get data from either and array or a string and let me show it in a UILabel. And the description method does this perfectly..... However you code makes it crash...

Comment: No really you should do ```temp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tmp];```